# How do I get portal name in 2sxc v.16.5.0 cshtml file that inherits Custom.Hybrid.Razor14?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a cshtml file that inherits `Custom.Hybrid.Razor14`. I can't change this inheritage since I need access to `Kit` property to update meta tags of the page. And I need to access portal name.
Dnn objects are available only within files/classes that inhering some Dnn namespace class.
I've tried to create a separate file helper in `.cs` file. But I didn't figure out how to access portal object from there to get its name. Documentation of 2sxc has huge amount of info but it seems useless for my case since I didn't succeed to find a missing peace of info there.
So how do I access portal name from there?

Here's my latest attempt to make it work. It's a `.cs` file with a helper that I was going to use in a `.cshtml` file that inherits `Custom.Hybrid.Razor14`.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using ToSic.Razor.Blade;
using ToSic.Sxc.Data;

public class DnnHelper : Custom.Hybrid.CodeTyped//Custom.Dnn.Razor12
{
    public string PortalName { get; set; }

    public DnnHelper()
    {
        PortalName = PortalSettings.PortalName; // throws exception as it can't find PortalSettings from here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first check out `CmsContext.Site` (or `MyContext` in `RazorTyped`) to see if it has what you need.

Otherwise you can just get the service `IDnnContext` which should get you going. [https://docs.2sxc.org/api/dot-net/ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Run.IDnnContext.html`](https://docs.2sxc.org/api/dot-net/ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Run.IDnnContext.html%60)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more specific answer that should just work with sample output.

```
@inherits Custom.Hybrid.Razor14

@using ToSic.Sxc.Services
@using ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Run

@{
  var MyDnn = GetService<IDnnContext>();
}

<pre>  
MyDnn.Portal
  @MyDnn.Portal.GetType()
  .PortalId:          @MyDnn.Portal.PortalId
  .PortalName:        @MyDnn.Portal.PortalName
  .EMail              @MyDnn.Portal.Email

MyDnn.Tab
  @MyDnn.Tab.GetType()
  .TabID              @MyDnn.Tab.TabID
  .TabName            @MyDnn.Tab.TabName

MyDnn.Module
  @MyDnn.Module.GetType()
  .ModuleID:          @MyDnn.Module.ModuleID
  .ModuleTitle:       @MyDnn.Module.ModuleTitle

MyDnn.User
  @MyDnn.User.GetType()
  .UserID             @MyDnn.User.UserID
  .Username           @MyDnn.User.Username
  .DisplayName        @(MyDnn.User.DisplayName ?? "Anon E. Mouse")
  .IsInRole("Hoser")  @MyDnn.User.IsInRole("Hoser")
  .Roles.Join()       @string.Join(", ", MyDnn.User.Roles)
</pre>
```